# .htaccess redirect to subfolder with language tag

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website where the .htaccess redirects to a subfolder.

This is the content of the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v2/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ v2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now when I install polylang and add a second language, it creates the URL `example.com/en`.

This URL gets me an error:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@reeko.com to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

When I open `example.com/v2/en` it does work properly. Now do I have to create a second redirection in my .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , put it before `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v2/` :

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$    /v2/en/$1  [L]
```

Clear browser cache then test it .

Comment: I still get the 500 error when opening example.com/en/

Comment: @margsenjo but still work when you add /v2/en/ right? did you clear brwoser cache ?

Comment: Yep it still works with /v2/en/ and I cleared the cache as well.
/en/ doesn't work.

Comment: @margsenjo see updated code and clear cache the test it

Comment: glad to help , Thanks

Comment: Now when I create a new page, I get the 500 Error again..
I created example.com/newpage. I can not even acces it via example.com/v2/newpage. Any idea?

Comment: @margsenjo first remove this line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v2/en/ , clear cache and test it